# Meaning of :: syntax

Tags: r, syntax

I am new to R, when reading functions documentation how do I interpret `::`?

How do I actually read the syntax?

```
readxl::read_excel()
```

Not sure if in R studio I can find any information about

Comment: thank you, I will have a look

Comment: You can open the relevant help page by typing `?\`::\``  into the console

Answer (score 2):

In R there are different packages available,
"readxl" is one of them.
When you install a package, you are ready to use its functionalities.
If you just need a sporadic use of a few functions or data inside the
package you can access them with the notation **packagename::functionname()**.

For example, since you have installed the readxl package, you can explore one of its   functionality called **read_excel()** to *import/read* excel sheet.

```
 Command to check what functions and data are contained in a package.  
 help(package = "packageName")
```

Comment: Brilliant! Now I understand :)

Comment: Hey,. If you like the answer, keep upvoting answer please, or You can accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I guess I voted, not sure how to accept it...